# app store app status remains waiting for upload.not uploading

Tags: iphone, app-store, uploading

i am trying to upload my application to app store.The status has changed to waiting for upload.But when the binary files are not uploaded.it shows uploading bar and says your application is being uploaded.I have waited nearly for an hour.But no change.Anyone faced such an issue?tried three times but always stays same.

Comment: i had a same issue...sometime the apple server are too busy..try again it will work..mine was uploaded after 4 tries..

Comment: how can i find the app bundle size

Comment: i got a new information that the iTunes has closed for winter holidays.I think it may be the reason.right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this email from Apple in November -

> iTunes Connect will be temporarily shut down from Thursday, December
>   22 to Thursday, December 29 for the winter holidays.
>
> During this shutdown, the following functionality will be unavailable:
>
> Access to iTunes Connect The delivery of any apps or updates
>   Additionally, the following will be delayed: Releases scheduled to
>   appear on the App Store for the first time Pricing changes scheduled
>   through the interval pricing system in iTunes Connect

So it may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It may take a long time depending on your app bundle size. Just wait.